# Twilio's Python WhatsApp API doesn't work with conditional flow statements based on responses

Tags: python, twilio

I'm experimenting with Twilio's WhatsApp API with Python but the conditional flow doesn't work. When I enter the word 'office' after getting the response 'What would you like to print?', I don't get the expected response 'Opening...'. I'd require some help regarding this.

```
from twilio.rest import Client
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def wa_print():
    """Respond to incoming messages with a simple text message."""
    question = request.values.get('Body')
    print(question)
    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    if (question == 'print'):
        resp.message('What would you like to print?')
        doc = request.values.get('Body')

        if (doc == 'office'):
            resp.message('Opening...')

    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Each time a user sends your WhatsApp number a message you will get a new request to your webhook endpoint. The new response will have the user's new message in the `Body` parameter.

In your example code you are always working with one response, so the variables `question` and `doc` are the same.

```py
def wa_print():
    """Respond to incoming messages with a simple text message."""
    question = request.values.get('Body')
    print(question)
    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    if (question == 'print'):
        resp.message('What would you like to print?')
        doc = request.values.get('Body')

        if (doc == 'office'):
            resp.message('Opening...')

    return str(resp)
```

Instead of nesting your conditionals, you could flatten them like this:

```py
def wa_print():
    """Respond to incoming messages with a simple text message."""
    question = request.values.get('Body')
    print(question)
    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    if (question == 'print'):
        resp.message('What would you like to print?')

    elif (question == 'office'):
        resp.message('Opening...')

    return str(resp)
```

With the above code, if someone messages "print" your application will respond "What would you like to print?" and if they message "office" the application will respond with "Opening...".

If you want to get more into controlling the conversation you can store state in HTTP cookies. I recommend checking this article on [creating SMS conversation in Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-python) to learn about that in more depth.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Yes, please take a look at the tutorial I linked to on SMS conversations in Python (SMS and WhatsApp are the same API, in this case).

Comment: Trying out your solution, I obtain the following error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'doc' referenced before assignment. How can I solve this?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, it shouldn't be `doc` at that point. It's really just `question`. I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: So there's no way to get two different responses and handle them separately?

Comment: All replies to your WhatsApp number will trigger a webhook request to your endpoint. You can treat responses differently by saving data in cookies like in the tutorial I linked to. That way you can get the first response "print" and save something that tells you the user last said "print". Then in the next response you can check to see if there's anything in the cookies about the previous response, and if it says "print" then you can branch. I recommend you implement the tutorial yourself to see how it all works.